# Playing an audio file in reverse using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, audio, media, exoplayer, audio-player

I want to play audio file backward using exoplayer (or other media player) in Android Device.

It says to be very difficult to play video backward:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2191

But, if I can reverse the pcm sample data stream going in player, I can play audio backward.

I'm now trying reverse part of music file using 'android.media.MediaExtractor' & 'android.media.MediaCodec'. But I can't create an reversed audio stream because I don't know how to create the header of sample data in short array.

The best option is to play audio file backward in ExoPlayer, the second option is create reversed audio stream and play it, the last option will be any method to play audio backward.

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: are you writing pcm data `.wav` format ?

Comment: @NileshDeokar I guess it is 16-bit wav format, but I'm not sure. The extraction and decoding program is from here : https://gist.github.com/a-m-s/1991ab18fbcb0fcc2cf9